# How to replace all the links in a notepad++ with a single link

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to know the regular expression exactly.
I want to replace href="abcd", href="xyz" and href="mno" etc with href="xxx".

Answer (score 4):

You can use : `(href=".*?")` and replace `href="xxx"` with replace all in notpad++

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
Find : href=(\"[^"]*\") 
Replace : href=(\"xxx\")
```